# Infinite loop is causing the form to not show up vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have an infinite loop in this sub because I want the program to keep testing this process to see if the variable has changed. When I run the program in the debugger, nothing shows up, including the form however when I removed the infinite loop from the program, the form showed up again. Does anyone know why this is happening? I should also mention I've tried a DO LOOP as well. Can anyone help?

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim greenCount As Integer
    Dim looptest As Boolean = True
    While looptest = True
        For Each control In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
            If control.BackColor = Color.Lime Then
                greenCount += 1
            End If
        Next
        txtFielder.Text = greenCount.ToString
    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: Well you're in a WHILE loop.  When does the condition become FALSE?

Comment: Duh, should have read the message fully and not just the title/code.

Comment: Why would you need to keep checking the `BackColor` of `Buttons` on your form in the first place? Do you need to run an infinite loop to test whether a `Button` has been clicked? Of course not. You handle the appropriate event. Maybe you should handle an event to know when the `BackColor` of your `Buttons` changes. In fact, why do you even need an event, given that it must be your code that changes the `BackColor` in the first place?

Comment: In a UI, you use events to test these conditions. What changes the BackColor of a Button to `Color.Lime`? See the BackColorChanged event.

Comment: Do consider the answers below... to answer your question as to why this happens though - you never leave the load event. It's still running because you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of all that code regardless. Depending on how you're changing the `BackColor` of those `Buttons` in the first place, updating the lime count might be best done there.  Otherwise, you should be handling the appropriate event, e.g.

```
Private limeButtonCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Buttons_BackColorChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.BackColorChanged,
                                                                               Button2.BackColorChanged,
                                                                               Button1.BackColorChanged
    If DirectCast(sender, Button).BackColor = Color.Lime Then
        limeButtonCount += 1
    Else
        limeButtonCount -= 1
    End If

    TextBox1.Text = limeButtonCount.ToString()
End Sub
```

Note that this code assumes that there are only two possible `BackColor` values and that all `Buttons` are not lime by default.  If your scenario is a bit more complex than that then you may need to change a code a little, e.g.

```
Private limeButtonCount As Integer = 0

Private Sub Buttons_BackColorChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.BackColorChanged,
                                                                               Button2.BackColorChanged,
                                                                               Button1.BackColorChanged
    limeButtonCount = Controls.OfType(Of Button)().Count(Function(b) b.BackColor = Color.Lime)

    TextBox1.Text = limeButtonCount.ToString()
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

[Form.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

This means that you'll never see your form as long as you loop in this event. You probably want to use the `Shown` event instead.

Comment: Have you tried running the test in a separate thread? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem

Comment: While I've answered the question itself, I should add that I don't think that an infinite loop is the right tool for what OP is doing. This said, creating some sort of watcher which runs on another thread would probably achieve what OP wants to achieve. Good thinking! I suspect OP might be a beginner, though, and if so he might struggle with implementing such logic.